# Can a dedicated IP address with a website on it be found and crawled by search engines?

Tags: search-engine, web-crawler

I have a VPS. I have placed a Drupal installation on that IP address. There is no URL registered for my website. The site on the IP address is for personal reference.

Can my IP address get indexed and found on search engines if there is no traditional URL for it? Will it get crawled?

I have no A-records pointing to it from other domain names I have on another VPS platform either. As far as I know, I am the only one that knows this IP address by heart or even goes there to add or refer to content.

Comment: If it is a VPS, it most likely will have an A-record, something like `vps-9999.newyork.yourprovider.com`

Comment: maybe webmasters.stackexchange.com?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: You're probably better off asking this question at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/. This site is about programming, while yours is not a question about programming.  

You can use the same account you use here to log in overthere.

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways I know for a search engine to learn about the existence a website.

1. You submit the domain to them directly.
2. Someone else links to the domain.
3. The search engine watches all domain registrations (Google can do this easily because they run a DNS themselves), and tries the standard prefixes (e.g. www).

There does not seem to be an automatic approach for discovering IP addresses with content unless someone links to it.

If it's purely for personal reference and you want to be sure no one else can access it, then you should implement security anyway. Don't just rely on no one knowing the IP.

Answer (score 0):

> Can my IP address get indexed and found on search engines if there is no traditional URL for it?

Yes, if you can reach it externally, then so can the search engines. If you don't want it to be indexed, add a "robots.txt" that requests for the site not to be indexed. Bear in mind that crawlers do not have to respect this, but the major ones do.

As for how the search engines discover IP addresses that are not indexed elsewhere, that is probably part of their "secret sauce" that we will never know about. Perhaps your IP has been used before, and it has previously been indexed in that context; if so, a search engine that has a poke around may be expecting that old site but will happily index your new one.

Or, maybe other IP addresses in the same netblock are in active use, and the search engines give yours "a quick try" to see if it responds on ports 80 (http) or 443 (https). If they do, it gets added to their indexes (or do-not-crawl lists, if your robots.txt requests it).

If you specifically do not want search engines to see your content, you could make the default home page blank, and put your Drupal installation in a sub-directory. The search engines will then have nothing to index apart from a blank home page.